# Authorize.net ARB Questions

Tags: php, authorize.net, payment-processing, recurring-billing, authorize.net-arb

I am working on an application that provides a 30 day trial, then the option to have a monthly or yearly subscription (at two different prices).

I've used a lot of the info provided by John Conde on his site (thanks John), but want to be sure I've got the right idea about how all this works - my first time doing anything with Authorize.net or subscriptions...

So if I have a 30 day trial, and someone decides they want to pay today, they should not be billed for 60 days. I set the start date ahead 60 days, but should I see any kind of charge in Authorize.net showing it's pending?

Next, is part of the ARB service that it "watches" for the renewal, or am I supposed to do something to trigger the check on a regular basis. I'm pretty sure that's what ARB is, and I don't need cron to check each day, but I'd rather ask a dumb question now rather than have a bunch of missing charges later.

Finally, what information would you recommend I store in my local DB and what should I let the ARB service capture. Currently, I'm storing what the subscription item is, who the person who is making payment is (by id), the name on the card, the last four digits of the card in case they want to reference what was used, the expiration date of the card, so I can look for pending expirations (unless this is part of ARB as well) and the date the subscription starts, ends.

Any additional info is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So if I have a 30 day trial, and
>   someone decides they want to pay
>   today, they should not be billed for
>   60 days. I set the start date ahead 60
>   days, but should I see any kind of
>   charge in Authorize.net showing it's
>   pending?

Use the AIM API to charge their initial payment and then set the start date in ARB to be in 60 days (when their first payment is). You won't get any notice that the subscription is "pending" but if a subscription ID is returned to you by the ARB API then it's safe to assume that first payment will be attempted in 60 days.

> Next, is part of the ARB service that
>   it "watches" for the renewal, or am I
>   supposed to do something to trigger
>   the check on a regular basis. I'm
>   pretty sure that's what ARB is, and I
>   don't need cron to check each day, but
>   I'd rather ask a dumb question now
>   rather than have a bunch of missing
>   charges later.

You don't have to do anything. The "A" in ARB stands for Automated and it is completely automated. Once a payment is scheduled it will run automatically until the subscription ends, you cancel the subscription, or their card expires and you don't update it before the next scheduled bill date.

> Finally, what information would you
>   recommend I store in my local DB and
>   what should I let the ARB service
>   capture. Currently, I'm storing what
>   the subscription item is, who the
>   person who is making payment is (by
>   id), the name on the card, the last
>   four digits of the card in case they
>   want to reference what was used, the
>   expiration date of the card, so I can
>   look for pending expirations (unless
>   this is part of ARB as well) and the
>   date the subscription starts, ends.

Send as much information to the ARB API as you can. It makes researching transactions in the Authnet control panel much easier as you can compare what you have captured to what they show in their transaction history.

It sounds like you're storing information that will be useful to you. I'd encrypt anything credit card related as to make it less useful if your DB gets hacked. You store enough information that a hacker could use it to convince your customers that they have their credit card number and then things get really ugly.

Comment: Thanks John. I tried to do the AIM check first, but was getting these errors:
Notice: Undefined variable: timeout in /path/AuthnetAIM.class.php on line 169
Notice: Undefined index: ch in /path/AuthnetAIM.class.php on line 147
I sent you a message via your contact form yesterday with some specific questions, if you're available.

Comment: Looks like you have a slightly older version of the code. Still,  those notices won't affect the functioning of the script. Your message didn't make it to my inbox if you want to try again. That way I can send you an updated script if you'd like.

Comment: Thanks. I just sent you a message via the form on your site.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in general you should avoid storing CC info (for security reason), so keeping everything at ARB would be better.

You should schedule the payments right when the user registers and set the startDate in the SOAP-call to 60 days later. Store the transaction key or however they call, so you can cancel the subscription at ARB anytime. If you do it that way, you can avoid handling payments at all and you just need to handle subscription and unsubscription.

Comment: Since no payment is due at the time of the purchase (because they're in the trial) wouldn't setting the start date to the end of the trial period be appropriate? Also with "last four" if that's all I'm storing, would this be bad from PCI point? I see things all the time (like Amazon) where they show me that info. I think it would help those who've paid to know which card they used... let me know if that's not the way to do it. Thx!

Comment: Storing the last four digit is ok, just don't store the full card-number unless you have really strict security and code-review policy. Setting the startDate 2 months ahead will leave the trial period free. The API manual says: "startDate: The date the subscription begins (also the date the initial billing occurs)". If the customer cancels the subscription, you cancel the scheduled payment and no charges will be made.